# OpenIDDict Registered User Email Confirmation

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Core with OpenIDDict. I'm employing views with cookie authentication and JWT for the OpenIDDict. Everything works perfectly save for the following scenerio:

Identity is changed to send a confirmation email to the user first to confirm their email address. The user gets the link by email and clicks it. They then login. Simple. In the meantime they can't access any pages.

But I noticed, using postman, they can access the solution via APi'S through OpenIDDict. They still get authorised. And as they get authorised they can access APIs.

Having just written this I've had a brain waive and I could simply introduce the code into the AuthenticationController during the exchange action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
    {
        Debug.Assert(request.IsTokenRequest(),
            "The OpenIddict binder for ASP.NET Core MVC is not registered. " +
            "Make sure services.AddOpenIddict().AddMvcBinders() is correctly called.");

        if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);
            //if (user == null)
            if (user == null || !(await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
            {
```

Works ! There u go...answered my own question. Mya help others in future

Answer (score 2):

While your solution works, you might prefer configuring ASP.NET Core Identity to make the "email confirmed" check for you when calling `SignInManager.CanSignInAsync(user)`. You can configure that in the Identity options:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But that addition to the AddIdentity is what triggers it in the first place ! So your right, that ensures a confirmation email be sent to a user.  The changes in my post are how then to handle it from the OpenIdDict as this also needs to check it. Also, for the sake of completeness, the email check should be posted in external provider checks as social media doesn't require it

Comment: You missed my point: using `IsEmailConfirmedAsync` in your own code is not necessary, as it's done for you by `CanSignInAsync` when the `RequireEmailConfirmation` option is enabled.

Comment: @Bhail https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/master/samples/PasswordFlow/AuthorizationServer/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs#L52